# Probability Per Action Question

Tags: probability

I want something to have an overall 1% probability rate of something happening given an action. This action will happen 48 times over the course of a weekend. Should the probability then be affected by the fact that it's being done 48 times? Is that increasing the overall probability? Is the rate per action something like 1%/48?

Comment: The probability of success, 1% is not effected by the number of times the trial is run, in this case 48. Take a look at binomial distributions for more information. What i mean by this is that no matter how many times you run it, the probability of success will still be 1%. However, the probability of one success in x runs will increase with x (up to a point).

Comment: Do you want the probability that the action takes place to be 1% or is it given that the probability for the action taking place 1%? That's not the same. If you are certain that the action is taking place, then what's the role of the probability then?

Comment: Yes, I want the action to be a 1% chance overall.

Answer (score 0):

If they are independent, $\frac {1\%}{48}$ per action is not far off.  It gives an expectation of $0.01$ times happening per weekend.  The chance of it happening over the weekend is a little less than $0.01$ because of the (small) chance that it happens more than once.

The exact calculation:  probability per action$=\frac 1{4800}$.
Probability not to happen in $48$ actions $=\left(\frac{4799}{4800}\right)^{48}$
 Probability to happen at least once in $48$ actions $=1-\left(\frac{4799}{4800}\right)^{48}\approx 0.00995$

Answer (score 0):

For 48 independent events for probability $p$, the probability of no events occurring is $(1-p)^{48}$. Set this to 0.99 and solve for p.

$$\begin{align}(1-p)^{48}&=0.99\\
48 log{(1-p)}&=log(0.99)\\
log{(1-p)}&=\frac{-0.00436}{48}\\
(1-p)&=10^{\frac{-0.00436}{48}}\\
(1-p)&=0.99979\\
p&=0.00021
\end{align}
$$